# FISH CLI What do the error numbers at the prompt mean?

Tags: command-line, prompt, fish, numbering

I am just trying out the **FISH** - (the FriendlyInteractiveSHell) - CLI & whenever I type in an erroneous Command, a new Prompt appears under the faulty Command prompt with a number in square brackets. I have searched through FISH's FAQs etc., but no joy in explaining the meaning of the error-number? If I hit Enter, the prompt just reappears with the error number until I enter a random correct command, such as 'ls'.

Comment: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#the-status-variable

Comment: **THANK YOU**  steeldriver! Problem **Solved**! :-))

Comment: ... it doesn't really explain why they show in your prompt - for that you would need to look at the contents of your fish_prompt function. See also [Weird artifact \[127\] after unknown command](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/6768)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number in brackets is the [exit status](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#variables-status) of the last command.

What this means depends entirely on the command. There is a strong understanding that returning 0 means success, but anything else signals *some* error and the command can choose the exact code.